# Order Hash and delete first key-value pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap, ruby-2.3

I have a Hash with timestamp as keys.

```
hash = {
  "2016-05-31T22:30:58+02:00" => {
          "path" => "/",
        "method" => "GET"
  },
  "2016-05-31T22:31:23+02:00" => {
          "path" => "/tour",
        "method" => "GET"
  },
  "2016-05-31T22:31:05+02:00" => {
          "path" => "/contact_us",
        "method" => "GET"
  }
}
```

I order the collection and get the first pair like this:

```
hash.sort_by {|k, _| k}.first.first
```

But how do I remove it?

The `delete` method [requires you](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete) to know the exakt spelling of the key. Of course I could return the key and then use it in the `delete` method, but I was thinking if there was any more straight forward way?

Comment: Note that `sort_by` returns an array.

Comment: I have now clarified the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `hash.keys` it returns an array of the keys:

`hash.delete(hash.keys.min)`

**EDIT**: I've updated the answer to reflect that keys must be sorted first, this has been added in the original question and brought up by @Shadwell in comments to this post.

I replaced `hash.keys.sort.first` for `hash.keys.min` as suggested by @Cary Swoveland, it is not only more performant but better semantically.

Comment: You'd need to sort the keys too I think to get the first one in order : `hash.delete(hash.keys.sort.first)` (I appreciate the title says an ordered hash but the question then sorts the keys explicitly)

Comment: I guess it depends if the keys are sorted or not, but that's not clear in the question. But yeah, you could sort them out too.

Comment: yeah, agreed, it's slightly unclear. Think you have the right approach though in both cases.

Comment: @Shadwell, why do you have to sort to find the smallest key?

Comment: I suggest `hash.keys.min` or `hash.min_by(&:first).first` rather than `hash.keys.sort.first`. Sorting should be avoided when only the smallest or largest value is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it definitely looks/reads better and I'll be using it. But why do you say sort should be avoided? As far as I can tell both `.min` and `.sort` depend on `<=>`.

Comment: Finding the minimum is much faster than sorting. Think about it, finding the minimum requires just a single pass through the array.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that! Thanks again for keeping up with me and explaining, you are right, a sort is likely  O(n log n), while finding the min is just O(n).

Comment: You don't have to state that you have updated your answer. Consider putting attributions in comments, to keep your answers "clean". If (in a comment) you thank the author of a comment for a suggestion and say that you've edited your answer to incorporate it), that's sufficient.

Answer (score 10):

Also note that `shift` can be used on the Hash values.

`hash.shift`

Removes the first key-value pair from the hash.  Works on arrays too.

Comment: Is not an array of hashes, it's simply a hash. `.shift` still works though.

Comment: You need to add the line `hash` after `hash.shift`, or possibly replace your line with `hash.tap { |h| hash.shift }`.

Comment: You only need to add `hash` after if you are returning the value, but the statement alone modifies hash, what happens later is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I wasn't aware of [Hash#shift](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-shift) (why no `Hash#pop`?). Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

As the OP has not stated that the hash's keys are in sorted order, we must assume that there is no guarantee that they are.

```
hash = { "2016-05-31T22:31:05+02:00"=>{ "path"=>"/tour", "method"=>"GET" },
         "2016-05-31T22:30:58+02:00"=>{ "path"=>"/", "method"=>"GET" },
         "2016-05-31T22:31:23+02:00"=>{ "path"=>"/contact_us", "method"=>"GET" } }
```

First, find the smallest key (the second one):

```
smallest_key = hash.keys.min
  #=> "2016-05-31T22:30:58+02:00"
```

This is obviously more efficient than sorting the keys then taking the smallest.

Because the date-time strings are in iso8601 format, they can be sorted as strings, without having to first convert them to `time` objects.

Then use [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if) to obtain the desired hash:

```
hash.reject { |k,_| k == smallest_key }
  #=> {"2016-05-31T22:31:05+02:00"=>{"path"=>"/tour", "method"=>"GET"},
  #    "2016-05-31T22:31:23+02:00"=>{"path"=>"/contact_us", "method"=>"GET"}}
```

To change `hash` in place, write

```
hash.delete(smallest_key }
hash
```

Comment: Don't loop to find the entry matching the key, that's O(n), if you have the key, simply use it, access to hashes is O(1).

Comment: Thanks, @Leito. That's a good suggestion for the case where the hash is to be mutated. (I did an edit.) If the hash is not to be mutated (the working assumption), one could write `h = hash.dup; h.delete(smallest_key); h`, but I prefer `reject`, which reads better (imo), does not require a non-block variable, is one line versus three and is probably not much worse performance-wise.

Comment: You are right, it depends on the desired result, mutateted hash or not. Performance depends on n, for smaller n's probably not, for bigger n's yes.

Comment: Downvoter: note that the OP does not reorder the hash's keys.